# Load compiled java class at runtime

Tags: java, runtime

I need to load plugins(class that implements my interface) at runtime. Adding a plugin is done by copying the compiled java class to the plugins folder in the working directory. I read a bunch of articles about this, but I still can't get this. I assume that I should get a list of .class files, then get byte codes for each file and define class or send it to class loader, right? If I'm right then how am I supposed to get byte codes?

Comment: Need more details. Are you actually "writing" your classes at runtime, or just need to load existing classes someone wrote manually? In latter case, Java actually doesn't provide you with any sort of lists that enumerates the class files, as that can be seen as a hook for injection attacks. Consider learning about [Service Loader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) mechanism. More about extensible applications [can be found here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/extensible-137159.html). I seriously advise you to go this route if only load.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov, I need to load existing compiled classes that implement certain interface. Interface has 2 methods: getName and excecute. So I want to be able to copy compiled classes into directory and load it at runtime.

Comment: I will still advocate for using `ServiceLoader` instead of directly loading from files. Or go for one of other established patterns and use Jar files with predefined format (usually with MANIFEST declaration of some sort where loaded class name is provided).

Answer (score 0):

It is actually not that difficult, create an instance of the built-in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html and point it to your directory. It will handle all the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: Class loader mechanism is not suitable for enumerating over class fiels, as the basis of loading the class is as simple as "class name in -> loaded class out" (with some exceptions). I don't think this question is concrete enough to actually answer it.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Enumerating over class files is as easy as enumerating over files in a directory. Or entries in a JAR file in a more complicated case.

Comment: @lexicore, it's only that easy in the easiest circumstance of class files really being stored in some directory somewhere. Class loader is not a file browser. He is free to do all he pleases as long as "class name in -> class out" rule holds true (and he should throw if he cannot do what he asks). Other than that, classes might be loaded from file system, classes can be loaded from net, classes can be generated based on some tokens in their name - there are no rules that you can just enumerate files to get all classes.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov It is directly stated in the question that "Adding a plugin is done by copying the compiled java class to the plugins folder in the working directory". So class files *are* stored in some directory somewhere. This makes the rest of your comment (although theoretically correct) irrelevant.